# 18+) Error:405 Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can't find any something wrong in my code. I think the Request("redirect:/" -> GetMapping("/")) should work.

This is my controller where the GET Request starts.

```
@PostMapping

public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors) {
    //if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        
    //return "orderForm";
    //}
    
    
    
    log.info("Order submitted: " + order);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

And

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use the same controller because in the first controller you have only post mapping, or specify the root of the second controller like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/home")
public class HomeController {
```

and then

```
   return "redirect:/api/home/"
```